# Youtube API v3 returning different or missing playlists

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having some problems with the v3 API when getting playlists by ID.

I have a javascript app that allows you to search for playlists (via a call to `www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`) then save those playlists to one of several "devices", which is then persisted on the server. When you return, the page gets the devices and the list of Youtube playlist IDs associated. To display more details (name, image, etc), call(s) are made to `www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists`.

The problem is that `/playlists` doesn't seem to be returning valid playlists. The most bare-bones test-case is a call to:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=KEY&part=id%2Csnippet&id=PL736C3116AD309B58`

which returns

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5cYuq_ImPkYn_h2RKDdX8DHvM2g/T0etSAnItCRUAPOtHRCu92sMKQU\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Note that it shows "totalResults: 1", but 0 actual results.

A call to the youtube website for the same playlist ID (http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL736C3116AD309B58) shows a valid playlist.

This used to work.

I'm not authenticating with oauth, but I'm comparing the results against non-authenticated web requests or against the non-oauthed API searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this is the case, but when clicking on one of the videos in the playlist you linked to, it shows SP736C3116AD309B58 as the playlistId (notice the prepending SP instead of PL).  However, I verified that the PL id was indeed to the one showing up in search...

But a call to this endpoint gives you the data you're looking for...
Call:

> [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key={API_KEY}&part=id%2Csnippet&id=SP736C3116AD309B58](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D&part=id,snippet&id=SP736C3116AD309B58)

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5cYuq_ImPkYn_h2RKDdX8DHvM2g/iOZzhrEf1VYbGO25CZhT4ga_Gw4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "SP736C3116AD309B58",
   "kind": "youtube#playlist",
   "etag": "\"5cYuq_ImPkYn_h2RKDdX8DHvM2g/U04KGNFEmQkvMoEC7XrbSayIGUY\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2009-04-21T15:23:31.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCNYrK4tc5i1-eL8TXesH2pg",
    "title": "Auto-Tune the News",
    "description": "The only news you need has a bass line",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hMtZfW2z9dw/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hMtZfW2z9dw/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hMtZfW2z9dw/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   },
   "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "public"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Is there any reason you aren't just capturing this data in the actual Search call?

Comment: This is via JS. On the server I'm saving the playlists associated with a "device". The problem is when, during a future session, I get the device's playlist IDs and want to show info. Not sure it's a good idea to persist all the data, and arguably against YT's no-caching rule.

Any thoughts on workarounds?