# Youtube API returning different playlist items

Tags: youtube-data-api

This is a similar issue to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082909/youtube-api-v3-returning-different-or-missing-playlists), however there is no search involved and I get different results for the exact same playlist `OLAK5uy_lOk7qDh2bFNSqCEbQYkHfUQYPlCynN7OQ`

The API call (**note: not a search**) returns a bunch of unavailable video ids:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=OLAK5uy_lOk7qDh2bFNSqCEbQYkHfUQYPlCynN7OQ&key={API_KEY}&part=snippet&maxResults=50
```

while using the website for the exact same playlist id

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_lOk7qDh2bFNSqCEbQYkHfUQYPlCynN7OQ
```

gives me completely different video ids, all of which are available. Is this a region issue?

Comment: Are you using ids from playlistitem.id or playlistitem.contentDetails.videoId ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource

Comment: Since I requested `snippet`, the id is extracted from `.snippet.resourceId.videoId`. I checked and it matches `contentDetails.videoId`.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent I think you're right about the region issue. From Colombia (*where I am*), I made the request to the `playlistItems` endpoint and I got different *video_ids* and *channel_id* even, when copy/pasting such ids in the browser - [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GveYnQ2AI_8) - it says `This video is not available` - but I can see the video is from that channel - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAOVL.png) - oddly enough, if I enter to the channel `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4IpV5hKYMP5dBqsKRrXjOA/videos` (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) it shows more videos (*14 in total*). Also, when copy/pasting the channel_id I got from the `playlistItems` request, it redirects me to the YouTube channel channel - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ/videos . So, it's a region issue or some unfinished migration/unification of artistic channels I read a few months ago = where YouTube is unifying all artistic/music channels per artist - and so each artist has his own official channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in having actual YouTube videos contained in the playlist, you can use either:

1. ```bash
   youtube-dl -j "OLAK5uy_lOk7qDh2bFNSqCEbQYkHfUQYPlCynN7OQ" | jq -r '.id'
   ```
2. my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/0f1f4281cbd3f70eca2d0c7feffc61089c5c01d5/playlistItems.php#L26-L46) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com) by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=OLAK5uy_lOk7qDh2bFNSqCEbQYkHfUQYPlCynN7OQ

Comment: Impressive work, Benjamin! This is the perfect answer.  The youtube-dl is a bit slow here, so second approach is the way to go if delay is an issue.

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)